# Parse a div with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I've this HTML code:

```
div class="singolo-contenuto link_azure">
<p><img src="" class="left pad2 field_foto" alt="" /><p> Message </p>    
</div>
```

I need to "capture" "Message".
I'm trying with:

```
String message = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='singolo-contenuto link_azure']").InnerText;
```

but doesn't works... I obtain a lot of the full page... what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The XPath expression you have just gets you to the `<div>` tag. You need to get deeper into the last `<p>` tag. This will work:

```
var message = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='singolo-contenuto link_azure']//p[last()]").InnerText;
```